# Where can I post generic software questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to post a question about hiding a particular tab in Google Chrome browser, but I am not sure which Stack Exchange site to post this question?

Comment: [superuser](https://superuser.com/) is the site for questions about computer hardware and software, so that would be the best fit. The only exception would be if your question is about using Chrome in a mobile operating system; that would be off-topic for superuser.

Comment: @gnat: Uh, there's nothing in there that's applicable to this question. The title of that FAQ is quite clear that it's about "computer science/programming", but that's exactly what this isn't. The one answer here suggests SU, but that's not even mentioned in either the FAQ question or its answer, and only one of the comments mentions it even tangentially. "Read this long FAQ" can be a bit off-putting, if perhaps still worth telling someone, but there's no point in telling someone to read a long FAQ about an unrelated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be the best Stack Exchange site for asking your question.